# insert ignore when exception raised by trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm triying to insert multiple rows with one insert query on a table that has a trigger launched before insert and raise duplicate-exception if a condition is true

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_registration` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `date_registration` (`date_registration`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (id)
(PARTITION id1k VALUES LESS THAN (1000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION id3k VALUES LESS THAN (3000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION id7k VALUES LESS THAN (7000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION id10k VALUES LESS THAN (10000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION id13k VALUES LESS THAN (13000) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 .........
```

Trigger code

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists users_before_insert //
create trigger users_before_insert before insert on users
for each row
begin
set @found := false;
select true into @found from users u where u.email = NEW.email;
if @found then
signal sqlstate '23000' set message_text = 'Email alread exists !';
end if;
end   //
delimiter ;
```

when i try to insert with duplicate records, even if the query uses ignore

exp:

```
insert ignore into users (first_name,last_name,date_registration,email,password) values
('aaaa','zzzz','2016-08-20','aaaa@mywebsite.com','strongpwd1'),
('bbbb','yyyy','2016-08-21','bbbb@mywebsite.com','strongpwd2'),
('cccc','xxxx','2016-08-22','aaaa@mywebsite.com','strongpwd3'),
('dddd','wwww','2016-08-23','dddd@mywebsite.com','strongpwd4');

ERROR 1644 (23000): Email alread exists !
```

qry aborted when it comes to the first duplicate 'aaaa@mywebsite.com'.

Is there a solution to ignore exception raised by trigger ?

Comment: Why are you using a trigger to emulate what `UNIQUE` index does? You are selecting an email to check if it exists - why? Why not place a unique index and just use `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? Solution to your problem isn't ignoring an `sqlstate` raised by trigger, the solution is using proper tools - in your case, proper tool is an index on the `email` field. It can even be made efficient by creating a field that contains a hash of the email so you will always have a fixed-length unique column in your table. Then your code is just a simple insert, no trigger needed.

Comment: Thanks @N.B. for your advice :)
but in case of using UNIQUE INDEX on `email`, I should add `id` to the constraint because of the partitioning rule :
_A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning_

Comment: If you use partitioning, then yes. However, the question is - why do you use partitioning in the first place? Are you partitioning the data on another hard drive or is it on the same one?

Answer (score 0):

No, while this trigger is active you cannot insert duplicate rows. 
It is not a good practice try to avoid a trigger, then you should think in changing the set of conditions required to fire the trigger instead.

Comment: Thanks @Liannis for your advice :)
I'll try to find a solution without trigger